# Restriction of an injective open map

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ : X → Y is an open mapping where X and Y are metric spaces. Suppose S is a subset of X and f is injective. I am trying to show that $f|_S$ is an open mapping if, and only if, $f(S)$ is open in Y .

My attempt is that $f|_S$ is an open mapping. Then let U be an open subset of S. then there is a open subset V of X such hat U=S $\cap$V. also $f$ is injective hence $f$(U)= $f$(S) $\cap$ $f$(V). $f$(U) and $f$(V) are open since $f|_S$ is an open mapping

Can I conclude also $f$(S) is open in Y?

For the other direction, I couldn't make much progress. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $S$ is open in $S$ of course. You can prove the other direction just like you did in $\implies$.

Comment: yes but I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: $f|_S$ open implies that it sends open sets (in $S$) to open sets (in $Y$). Now, $S$ is open in $S$.

Comment: thanks a lot :D

Comment: Do the same as you did in your attempt: take an open set $U$ in $S$, and prove that $f(U)$ is open in $Y$ using that $f(S)$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: Okay thank you very much again!